# Can I allow some specific applications get access of desktop created by CreateDesktopA function

Tags: c#, winapi

By using windows API function [`CreateDesktopA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createdesktopa) I have created vitual desktop and launched my application within it.

I will surprise if is there anything which will restrict all other applications to get access of virtual desktop. In other words only mentioned applications will see/access virtual desktop.

Code to create desktop and launching c# winform:

```
static void Main()
{
    IntPtr hOldDesktop = GetThreadDesktop(GetCurrentThreadId());

    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
    sa.bInheritHandle = 1;
    sa.nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(sa);

    IntPtr hNewDesktop = CreateDesktopExA("myDesktop", IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, 0, (uint)DESKTOP_ACCESS.GENERIC_ALL, ref sa);

    SwitchDesktop(hNewDesktop);

    string passwd = "";

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        SetThreadDesktop(hNewDesktop);

        Form loginWnd = new Form();
        TextBox passwordTextBox = new TextBox();

        passwordTextBox.Location = new Point(10, 30);
        passwordTextBox.Width = 250;
        passwordTextBox.Font = new Font("Arial", 20, FontStyle.Regular);

        loginWnd.Controls.Add(passwordTextBox);

        Application.Run(loginWnd);

    }).Wait();

    SwitchDesktop(hOldDesktop);

    CloseDesktop(hNewDesktop);
}
```

Comment: Windows' security model is based in users, not processes. So no, you cannot restrict access to your desktop to specific apps, only to specific users.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, okay. At least can I get list of apps which is accessing the virtual desktop?

Comment: Get the list of apps should be just getting the number of processes running on the virtual desktop